# Synchronising a fast, inaccurate timer with a slow, precise?

Tags: timer, measurement

I am in an interesting situation. My chip needs to track both microsecond time intervals, as well as hours. However, instead of adding a crystal, I insist on the internal RC oscillator, frequency error up to 10%.

The external signal is 50Hz (guess from where).

What software approach (algorithm) can I use to combine the two clocks in a single, with both high resolution and accuracy? It should fit a small 8-bit processor and exhibit good smoothness (e.g. no possibility for negative duration events)?

Comment: how accurate is your 50Hz signal?

Comment: what micro controller are you using ?

Comment: @Pradheep, I think the accurate frequency is 50.00Hz (i.e. error in the thousandths). The micro is an atmega8, but that is not important - I am asking about ingenious algorithms to merge two clocks.

Comment: That is, and internal 16bit timer ticks every us. On overflow, result is added to a global variably, so that I can track long periods of time. And the externakl clock comes as an interrupt every 20ms